# How to get normalized values from groupby and size

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I know that we can get normalized values from `value_counts()` of a pandas series but when we do a group by on a dataframe, the only way to get counts is through `size()`. Is there any way to get normalized values with size()?

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subset_product':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C'],
                   'subset_close':[1,1,0,1,1,1,0]})
df2 = df.groupby(['subset_product', 'subset_close']).size().reset_index(name='prod_count')

df.subset_product.value_counts()
A    3
B    2
C    2
```

df2

[image]

Looking to get:

```
subset_product subset_close prod_count norm
A              0            1          1/3
A              1            2          2/3
B              1            2          2/2
C              1            1          1/2
C              0            1          1/2
```

subset_product
Besides manually calculating the normalized values as prod_count/total, is there any way to get normalized values?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it is not possible only one `groupby` + `size` because `groupby` by 2 columns `subset_product` and `subset_close` and need `size` by `subset_product` only for normalize.

Possible solutions are [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size as `df2` with [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['subset_product', 'subset_close']).size().reset_index(name='prod_count')
s = df.subset_product.value_counts()
df2['prod_count'] = df2['prod_count'].div(df2['subset_product'].map(s))
```

Or:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['subset_product', 'subset_close']).size().reset_index(name='prod_count')
a = df2.groupby('subset_product')['prod_count'].transform('sum')
df2['prod_count'] = df2['prod_count'].div(a)
```

---

```
print (df2)
  subset_product  subset_close  prod_count
0              A             0    0.333333
1              A             1    0.666667
2              B             1    1.000000
3              C             0    0.500000
4              C             1    0.500000
```